# facing issue with nginx URL rewriting this url https://webserver.com into https://webserver.com/access

Tags: nginx

I'm facing issue with nginx URL rewriting this url https://webserver.com into https://webserver.com/access. i m new to nginx with basic knowledge.

current nginx config as below

```
upstream app1 {
    server 192.168.250.62:443;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name app1.webserver.com;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.key;
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://app1;
    }
    location / {
        return 301 /access;
    }
}
```

Comment: you failed to mention what the issue is.

Comment: getting error with "too many redirects" and page not loading.

Comment: Remove the second redundant `location {}` block for starters.

Comment: i tried to remove it, but its reaching to https://webserver.com only, but we need to reach https://webserver.com/access

Comment: Try: `location = / { return 301 /access; }`

Comment: its working... thanks @RichardSmith